# I want to change the translation that appears in the description of "Migrated Questions"

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, localization

In https://ja.stackoverflow.com , Notification that appears in a question that has been migrated to another site,
The "description" of the destination site is displayed, which is hard to understand.

> Ja: "**professional and enthusiast programmers**" で回答できるため、この質問は Stack Overflow に移行されました。
>
> En: This question was migrated to Stack Overflow because it can be answered by "**professional and enthusiast programmers**".

However, questions migrated from other sites and the name of the source site are displayed on other sites, making it easy to understand.

> Ja: この質問はスタック・オーバーフローで回答できるため "**Japanese Language Stack Exchange**" から移行されました。
>
> En: This question was migrated from "**Japanese Language Stack Exchange**" because it can be answered on スタック・オーバーフロー.

Problem is because that refer to the translation of the string `$destinationSiteAudience$`, Will be permitted to (With the consent of the community) change this part?

**Original String:**

> This question was migrated to [$toSiteName$]($destinationUrl$ "$postTitle$") because it can be answered by $destinationSiteAudience$.

Comment: To the person who voted to close this question: MSE is the correct place for posts about localization bugs and feature requests as this applies to the engine used on all sites and no SE devs read localized Metas.

Comment: Also, the team has stated that English-language questions about localized sites should be asked here, as the respective per-site metas only accept questions in the language in question.

Answer (score 1):

The text for the notices for migrations when the source/destination language is different have been changed to no longer pull anything from the Db, and are now fully translatable. For migration notices between sites with the same language code the notice is the same.